# BigCommerce Order API Shipping Address XML does not match actual order

Tags: bigcommerce

We have an order in BigCommerce that shows a shipping email address that is different from the address displayed when we request shipping information from the API.

Specifically, the Shipping area on the order page looks like this:

[image]

When I request the the `/api/v2/orders/{order id}/shippingaddresses.xml`, it has a different email address:

```
<addresses>
   <address>
      <id>21551</id>
      <order_id>21873</order_id>
      ...
      <email>XXXX@gmail.com</email>
      ...
   </address>
</addresses>
```

The email address being returned in the XML is the address originally entered on the order. The address was later edited by a staff member, but the API still returns the old address.

I have triple-checked that this is the same order.

Is this "Shipping" email address shown in the UI different from the one in `shippingaddresses.xml`?

Comment: Jesus... sounds like such a typical BC bug.  Can't help, but just wanted to comment and share my sympathies.

Comment: Sympathies appreciate. So glad I'm not working on that project anymore :)